# On iPad, is it possible to drag/drop a handwritten note from Apple Notes

Tags: ipad, drag-and-drop, ios11

In apple notes, I can drag and drop a note and get text, but I can't seem to find an provider for getting at a handwritten note (a sketch).  I see it's working when dropping into pages/keynote, so it does work.  Has anyone worked this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple responded:

Apple Developer Relations
September 28 2017, 11:55 AM
This issue behaves as intended based on the following:  If you drag a whole note (from the notes list) we supply an attributed string as one of the data types. The drawing will be converted to an image attachment. We also do this if you drag a selection that includes an inline drawing from the note editor text view. If you drag a selection that is *only* the inline drawing (1 character), we supply an image (public.jpeg) and also the com.apple.drawing data type (which isn’t a public data type yet).  If you drag a fullscreen drawing we supply the image of the drawing.  Please update your bug report to let us know if this is still an issue for you.